# How to create a command with at least one option

Tags: java, picocli

I'd like to create a command that allows for the user to specify one of the available options to execute a command. For example herein is a list of services and the command is status. The user can issue the a command **'status --list scarlet garnet cardinal'** for a partial set or **'status --all'** for a complete set of services. I have implemented the following :

```
@Command(name = "status", description = "checks the status of a service")
public void status(
        @Option(names = "--all", description = "checks all services.") boolean all,
        @Option(names = "--list", arity = "0..1", description = "checks specified services.") boolean list,
        @Parameters(paramLabel = "<service>", description = "a list of service names") List<String> services) {
    if (all) {
        System.out.println("check all");
    } else if (list) {
        System.out.println("check listed");
    }
}
```

It works, however there's a bug, that is, if a user just supplies the command only **"status"** without any further arguments it is considered valid. I believe this happens because both options are boolean.
How do we rectify this to have at least one of the optional options provided ?

Comment: use some if-checks, if no other provided, throw an Exception

Comment: Well that was my last resort, however I was hoping for a solution that would use picocli features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get the desired behaviour by changing the `--list` option from a boolean to an array or collection of Strings.

For example:

```java
@Command(name = "status", description = "checks the status of a service")
public void status(
        @Option(names = "--all", description = "checks all services.") boolean all,
        @Option(names = "--list", arity = "1..*", paramLabel = "<service>",
                description = "checks specified services.") List<String> services) {
    if (all) {
        System.out.println("check all");
    } else if (services != null && !services.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("check listed");
    }
}
```

If the options are mutually exclusive, you can use an [ArgGroup](https://picocli.info/#_mutually_exclusive_options).

But perhaps the simplest solution for this case is to have no options, only a list of services to check. If the user does not specify a service, then the app would check all services.

In code:

```java
@Command(name = "status",
  description = "Checks the status of all services, or only the specified services.")
public void status(
        @Parameters(paramLabel = "<service>", arity = "0..*",
                    description = "A list of service names. Omit to check all services.") 
        List<String> services) {
    if (services == null || services.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("check all");
    } else {
        System.out.println("check listed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really helpful. I really like the simple solution,  how did I not think of that!!

Comment: Hi Remko, I forgot to mention that in your simple solution, when the List<String> Services has no values, it is summitted as null and so .isEmpty throws a NullPointerException.